# Firestore disable write access from web admin console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am the owner of the Firebase project.

Is it possible (for accidental data manipulation reasons) to disable write access from Firestor DB?

For instance when login in the web admin console e.g.
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/MYPROJECTID/database/firestore

to not be able to write/update/delete any documents or collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable write access to web and mobile clients, you can set the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to disallow all writes.  There is no other configuration to control client access.

For backend code, and collaborators accessing the database through the Firebase console, you can only revoke access to any services accounts that might be used to make changes using [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam).